# How to speed up the transform from binary file to HDF5 file?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have `.dat` binary file and want to transform it to `.h5` file.So I write this code:

```
import os
import h5py
import numpy as np
import struct
import random
float_size=4

input_node=1534
output_node=256
input_file='./data/training_normalization_Target_ForWolfram.dat'
out_file=r'./data/training_normalization_Target_ForWolfram.h5'

input_and_output_node=input_node+output_node
with open(input_file,'rb') as f:
    f.seek(0,os.SEEK_END)
    file_len=f.tell()/(float_size*input_and_output_node)
    print 'the size of input_file is '+str(os.path.getsize(input_file)/(1024**3.))+' GB'

with h5py.File(out_file, "w") as f:
    Input =  f.create_dataset('Input', (file_len,input_node),dtype='float',chunks=True,compression='gzip')
    Output = f.create_dataset('Output',(file_len,output_node),dtype='float',chunks=True,compression='gzip')
    index=range(0,file_len)
    random.shuffle(index)
    with open(input_file,'rb') as fin:
        print 'it will iterate '+ str(file_len) +' times'
        for i in range(file_len):
            print i
            fin.seek(float_size*input_and_output_node*index[i],os.SEEK_SET)
            Input[i,:]  = np.array(struct.unpack('<'+str(input_node )+'f',fin.read(float_size*input_node)))
            Output[i,:] = np.array(struct.unpack('<'+str(output_node)+'f',fin.read(float_size*output_node)))
```

But it's too too slow...(the size of `.dat` file is about 19.45 GB)
So how to improve the speed of transform?

[image]

if not use any `compression`,it slightly faster(about 10 times).But for this big file,it's very slow indeed.

Comment: Is the only change `chunks=True,compression='gzip'`?

Comment: How slow is slow? Have you tested that reading data is optimal? Have you tried different compressions, like blosc, for output?

Comment: @kakk11 I edit my question